# How To Create Custom Page Template?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

In the Lightning App UI, can I create a custom page template? I see you can "Change" and select from a list:

[image: select page template]

But how do I create a custom one to add to the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are called [Custom Lightning Page Template Component's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm), and yes, you can create your own.

> Custom Lightning page template components are supported for record
> pages, app pages, and Home pages.

Not available in lwc yet, only Aura.

Basic Sample:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate" description="Main column
 and right sidebar. On a phone, the regions are of equal width">
    <aura:attribute name="left" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="right" type="Aura.Component[]" />
 
    <div>
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow"
                                  class="slds-m-right_small">
                {!v.left}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="{! $Browser.isDesktop ? '4' : '6' }"
                                  class="slds-m-left_small">
                {!v.right}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Once created, will this appear in the list of templates that appear when I click the "Change" button (as highlighted in the screenshot above)?

Comment: as long as you implement the appropriate interface, yes. The doc is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

We can create custom lightning page template using Component Facets in aura.At first we create attribute for each column and specify size for column in component file.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate;" description="5 columns flexible without header and footer." >
    <!-- Make attribute for each column -->
    <aura:attribute name="column1" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Column1"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column2" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Column2"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column3" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Column3"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column4" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Column4"/>
    <aura:attribute name="column5" type="Aura.Component[]" description="Column5"/>
   
    
    <div>
        <!-- Specify the area for each column -->
        <lightning:layout  pullToBoundary="small">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">
                {!v.column1}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">         
                {!v.column2}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">         
                {!v.column3}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">         
                {!v.column4}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">         
                {!v.column5}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

Then we Configure Template Regions and Components in the Design Resource.

```
<design:component label="5 columns flexible without header and footer.">
    <flexipage:template >
      <flexipage:region name="column1" defaultWidth="Small" />
      <flexipage:region name="column2" defaultWidth="Small" />
      <flexipage:region name="column3" defaultWidth="Large" />
      <flexipage:region name="column4" defaultWidth="Small" />
      <flexipage:region name="column5" defaultWidth="Small" />
  </flexipage:template>
     <design:supportedFormFactors>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
    </design:supportedFormFactors>
</design:component>
```